# EF6 Type of Join

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to figure out how to declare a join object.  I understand that I can use the word var and be done with it, but I wish to fully understand the type of object that comes back and how I would declare such an object.  Here is my example that I am trying to make work:

```
IQueryable<TeamMember, Member> j =
                Db.TeamMembers.Join(Db.Users,
                c => c.MemberId,
                cm => cm.Id,
                (c, cm) => new { TeamMember = c, Member = cm })
                .Where(m => m.TeamMember.TeamId == team.Id && !m.TeamMember.MemberId.Equals(team.CaptainId));
```

However the above code does not work, the error that I get is

> Incorrect number of type parameters.

How would I accomplish the above?

Comment: You can let Intellisense do the work for you.

Use `var`, possibly compile, and hover with the mouse over the `var` keyword (not the variable name). The tooltip will contain the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IQueryable` only accepts **1 type** (`IQueryable<T>`)

That explains the error message you have.

In your JOIN query, you're returning `anonymous` type (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/bb397696.aspx), so what you can use is

- `IQueryable<object> j =`
- `IQueryable<dynamic> j =`
- `var j =`

There's no way to know the type with your current code, but you can always create another model and use it

Comment: I have been trying to avoid creating another object if I can, but it looks like I must.

Comment: @Bagzli: it's fine to create new object just for display purpose (ViewModel) or for transfer purpose (DataTransferObject)